# When creating thread safe reads in Swift, why is a variable create outside the concurrent queue?

Tags: swift, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch

```
public class Account {
    // MARK: Initializer
    // Custom initializer

    // MARK: Stored Properties
    let concurrentQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(
        label: "concurrentQueue",
        qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated,
        attributes: [DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent]
    ) 

    private var _name: String

    public name: String {
        get { 
            return self.concurrentQueue.sync { return self._name } 
        }

        set {
            self.concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self._name = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say you have a class like above where you want thread safety.

What is the difference between the getter in the `Account` class and defining the getter like this?

```
get { 
    var result: String!
    self.concurrentQueue.sync { result = self._name } 
    return result
}
```

I'm currently wrapping my head around thread safety and I always see reads created like the latter. It seems to me they're virtually the same... am I wrong?

Source: [GCD Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1)

Comment: The latter is just a more convoluted version of achieving the former

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. There are two `DispatchQueue.sync` methods:

```
public func sync(execute block: () -> Swift.Void)
public func sync<T>(execute work: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T
```

and in your first example the second one is used: The closure can return a value, which then becomes the return
value of the `sync` call. Therefore in

```
get { 
    return self.concurrentQueue.sync { return self._name } 
}
```

the return value of `sync { ... }` is `self._name` and that is returned
from the getter method. This is equivalent to (but simpler than) storing the
value in a temporary variable (and here the closure returns `Void`):

```
get { 
    var result: String!
    self.concurrentQueue.sync { result = self._name } 
    return result
}
```

Of course that works only with *synchronously* dispatched closures,
not with asynchronous calls. These are stored for later execution and must
return `Void`:

```
public func async(..., execute work: @escaping @convention(block) () -> Swift.Void)
```