# How do I refactor my code to call AppDelegate on the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swift4

I recently started migrating my project from Swift3/Xcode8 to Swift4/Xcode9. My app crashes at runtime because the main thread sanitizer allows access to `UIApplication.shared.delegate` only on the main thread, resulting in a crash at startup. I have the following code, which worked fine in Swift 3 -

```
static var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
}
```

Other classes in my code make access to appDelegate. I need to figure out a way to return `UIApplication.shared.delegate` from the main thread.

**Note**: Using an `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` block from wherever access is made to `appDelegate` is not an option. Need to use it only within the `static var appDelegate` declaration only.

Looking for a clever workaround.

Relevant crash message:

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication delegate]
>   PID: 1094, TID: 30824, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x60400043c540 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0

Comment: what about just wrapping it in DispatchQueue.main.sync?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Asleepace, but that happens to be the first thing I tried. You can't return from within a closure.

Comment: @entropy.maximum: You *can* return a value from `.sync { ..}`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569118/when-creating-thread-safe-reads-in-swift-why-is-a-variable-create-outside-the-c for an example. But  dispatching synchronously to the main thread might create a deadlock.

Comment: The correct way to fix this would be to have whatever uses the AppDelegate only call it from the main thread. In fact you shouldn't be calling the AppDelegate like this at all, could dependency injection help your requirement so the AppDelegate didn't need to be accessed instead? By looking for a direct solution to the problem at hand you are simply going to be patching the problem rather than fixing it properly.

Comment: @dlbuckley you're right. But I'm prohibited from modifying the rest of the codebase, because more than one call is being made to access this property, all over the project.

Comment: Shouldn't we be asking why the OP needs to access the Application Delegate from other parts of the code?

Comment: @maddy it is worth mentioning that _Xcode_ allows to switch on/off the Thread Sanitizer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/thread_sanitizer/enabling_the_thread_sanitizer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved by using Dispatch Groups.

```
static var realDelegate: AppDelegate?;

static var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
    if Thread.isMainThread{
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
    }
    let dg = DispatchGroup();
    dg.enter()
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        realDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate;
        dg.leave();
    }
    dg.wait();
    return realDelegate!;
}
```

and call it somewhere else for

```
let appDelegate = AppDelegate(). realDelegate!
```

Comment: What's the difference between this solution and Debaprio B's solution?

Answer (score 4):

I use the following:

```
static var shared: AppDelegate? {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            return UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        }

        var appDelegate: AppDelegate?
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        }
        return appDelegate
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because the code within `DispatchQueue.main.sync` will not be executed before the value is returned.

Comment: It's a `sync` which means the non-main thread waits till the value is returned.