# Xcode 9 Main Thread warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode9

```
+(BOOL)isExecutingInBackground {
    __block BOOL retVal = NO;
    if(IS_THIS_MAIN_THREAD) {
        retVal = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground;
    }
    else {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            retVal = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground;
        });
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

With the new `Xcode-9` we are getting too many warnings for `UI` functions being called in `main thread`. With that warning in place, code like above has been introduced at many places. The con sides are

1. This can potentially also introduce `deadlock` on threads (in a multi-threaded app)
2. This check has inflated code at many places.

My question is this:

1. The above code, is that only way to solve this warning? If not, what are other better ways?
2. What methods can I use to ensure that there are absolute no thread locks in my code [even in race conditions]
3. Is there a way out from this warning?
4. Is the warning, at all important [if we are not performing any UI update]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45832155/how-do-i-refactor-my-code-to-call-appdelegate-on-the-main-thread